# Allowing only letters for onkeyup function. While also negating keys like PgUp, Del, ArrowLeft etc

Tags: javascript, function

I'm very new to Javascript and I have an assignment to create a letter guessing game. I have it all done and wanted to go the extra mile and create an alert when something other than a letter is pressed. I found this great example a day or two ago..

toLowerCase() != key.toUpperCase()

But the input can still be any arrow key and the six keys above it. The onkeyup retuns a string for these and I'm trying to use charAt(1) to single them out. But it's not working.

```
function isLetter(key) {
  if (key.toLowerCase() != key.toUpperCase() && key.charAt(1) === '') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

and the key up function

```
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  keyPress = event.key;
  if (!isLetter(keyPress)) {
    return alert('Enter a letter');
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need track only english letters? Or other languages like russian applyable?

Comment: Only English letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Your approach has a potential bug. Which is the key <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> etc. will also pass the test.</strike>

It's probably better to use a regular expression to test the key stroke:

```js
function isLetter(key) {
 // This regular expression tests if the key is only a single character from a to z
 return key.match(/^[a-z]$/); 
}

document.onkeyup = function (event) {
 keyPress = event.key;
 if (!isLetter(keyPress)) {
  return alert('Enter a letter');
 }
}
```

Comment: To make it case insensitive: `/^[a-z]$/i` or `/^[a-zA-Z]$/`

Comment: The toLowerCase() part of the function takes care of the + and - keys. I haven't learned the .match property yet. But thank you for the working answer.

Comment: Agree. But better not use regexp in these simple cases. You can use ASCII for detecting English letter: `'a' <= key && key <= 'z'`.

Comment: @XaveScor I don't think there's anything wrong with regex and also that code doesn't account for capital letters or strings with length greater than 1. False positive: 'aaa', False negative: 'A'.

Comment: @XaveScor I'm still able to press the arrow keys and other keys above it without getting an alert using your argument.

Comment: @Khauri key cannot be the string with a length greater than 1. For case insensitive you can do:
`const lower = key.toLowerCase(); return 'a' <= lower && lower <= 'z';`

Comment: I also tried `key.length === 1' to filter out the arrowkeys. Also not working.

Comment: @Billwee Are you sure? Make sure the document is currently focused while you pressing the key.

Comment: Yeah. it is. I have an array outputting the guesses onto the page and it's displaying arrowup , arrowleft , arrowdown , arrowright  etc..

Comment: @Billwee That should not be happening. Can you show us the code that you have updated?

Comment: Right now I have 
`function isLetter(key) {
  if (key.toLowerCase() != key.toUpperCase() && key.length === 1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
`
and nothing has changed for my keyup function

`document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  keyPress = event.key;
  if (!isLetter(keyPress)) {
    return alert('Enter a letter');
  }`

Comment: @Billwee For me it works as it supposed to. Make sure there's no syntax error in your code(noticing you're missing a `}` at the end), no cache taken in the place, no key recording after failing the test. Everything should be fine.

Comment: I dumped my live server and restarted it. Now it works. I apologize for the mix up and thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the direct code of any input symbol. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

```js
const ACode = 65;
const ZCode = 90;
function isLetter(key) {
    return ACode <= key && key <= ZCode;    
}

document.onkeyup = function (event) {
    keyPress = event.keyCode;
    if (!isLetter(keyPress)) {
        return alert('Enter a letter');
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry.. This doesn't work either. at least for the arrow keys and the six keys above it.

Comment: I don't think it works because there are no real ascii values for those keys. right?